# Veritasium video about mosquitoes

Tags: human-genetics, experiment, mosquitoes

In the recent veritasium video about mosquitoes , the host says that the researchers used identical female twins and fraternal female twins to understand the effect of genes on attractiveness to mosquitoes.
Is there a scientific reason to use only female test subjects for the experiment?

The video:
https://youtu.be/38gVZgE39K8

Comment: My guess is that there is no reason for choosing female per se. Rather, I'm guessing that they simply wanted to avoid complications regarding sex differences, so they simply created the experiment with participants being of the same sex. So I suspect the experiment could just as well have been created with only males.

Comment: Female and male mosquitoes are quite different, studying both would be like studying different species in many ways and females are the ones that bite, so likely that is why.